# Reading the page source of a website using HttpURLconnection

Tags: java, cookies, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to read the page source of a site in a way that each time i open the site with different ID.
I'm manage to read 5-6 pages but after that i read the pages with serves notice: "please activate browser cookies to view this site"
I know I need to manage the cookies in a certain way, but any way I tried did not work.

That's my code:

```
public void read_and_save_pages() {

    for (String id : ids) {
        try {

            // open url
            URL url = new URL(link + id);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // set user agent
            connection
                    .setRequestProperty(
                            "User-Agent",
                            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36");

            // read page source code
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream(), "windows-1255"));

            // create file to write
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(
                    path + ".html");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

            // write file
            String line = in.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                out.write(line + '\n');
                line = in.readLine();
            }
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [CookieManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html)?

Comment: BTW you should not only close your FileWriter, but also tell HttpURLConnection and the InputStream that it's over.